# Elasticsearch query_shard_exception failed to create query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to execute the following query in Elasticsearch 6.2:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "published": {
              "value": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "test",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "description"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I got this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"must\" : [\n      {\n        \"term\" : {\n          \"published\" : {\n            \"value\" : true,\n            \"boost\" : 1.0\n          }\n        }\n      },\n      {\n        \"query_string\" : {\n          \"query\" : \"test\",\n          \"fields\" : [\n            \"description^1.0\",\n            \"name^1.0\"\n          ],\n          \"type\" : \"best_fields\",\n          \"default_operator\" : \"or\",\n          \"max_determinized_states\" : 10000,\n          \"enable_position_increments\" : true,\n          \"fuzziness\" : \"AUTO\",\n          \"fuzzy_prefix_length\" : 0,\n          \"fuzzy_max_expansions\" : 50,\n          \"phrase_slop\" : 0,\n          \"escape\" : false,\n          \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n          \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}",
        "index_uuid": "9R0Sz_zBTtmzrZ-WFj_I9w",
        "index": "my_index"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "my_index",
        "node": "ATA0gX7XQeCXwpsUfTNbsg",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_shard_exception",
          "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"must\" : [\n      {\n        \"term\" : {\n          \"published\" : {\n            \"value\" : true,\n            \"boost\" : 1.0\n          }\n        }\n      },\n      {\n        \"query_string\" : {\n          \"query\" : \"test\",\n          \"fields\" : [\n            \"description^1.0\",\n            \"name^1.0\"\n          ],\n          \"type\" : \"best_fields\",\n          \"default_operator\" : \"or\",\n          \"max_determinized_states\" : 10000,\n          \"enable_position_increments\" : true,\n          \"fuzziness\" : \"AUTO\",\n          \"fuzzy_prefix_length\" : 0,\n          \"fuzzy_max_expansions\" : 50,\n          \"phrase_slop\" : 0,\n          \"escape\" : false,\n          \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n          \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}",
          "index_uuid": "9R0Sz_zBTtmzrZ-WFj_I9w",
          "index": "my_index",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "number_format_exception",
            "reason": "For input string: \"true\""
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I'm new to Elasticsearch. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the `caused_by` portion of the return JSON points to the term query as being the issue.  What happens if you switch it to use a String `"true"`?  ES should interpret a String representation as a boolean value if the data type is boolean.

Comment: If you can post the mapping of your index as well, that should make it clear.

Comment: @ryanlutgen The value for term query is 0/1 stored in ES. When I changed it to `1`, it works. I imported data from MySQL to ES using logstash, so it saved as 0 or 1 instead of boolean. Can I import them as boolean?

Comment: I am not familiar with logstash, but you could write an ingest pipeline to convert SQL bit values to booleans, or ensure your mapping is set to Boolean for that field if it isn't.

Comment: I changed to the MySql field to `tinyint(1)` that is matched to `boolean` type in ES. Thanks.